# Any SSL cert works with node

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, devops

First I'm not talking about emitting my own certs to the dev environment, I need a CA cert for the prod environment. I have a Node app running into an EC2 instance using PM2. That being said my doubt is when I buy a cert I have to put a domain, but freaking ec2 is just an IP, should I put the IP as the domain for the SSL?

Comment: End up using own Amazons services to emit the SSL. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html.
Basic need to emit the cert on AWS Certificate Manager, then set up a load balancer and add the cert to it

Comment: For thanks for the info. But for your solution you also need your own domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get proper HTTPS for your instance you must have **your own domain**. IP can't be used. Ssl cert for the instance can be obtained for free if you have domain. Popular choice is **LetsEncrypt** which is also used by Stackoverflow for its own Ssl certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest solution is to use AWS certificate manager and tie that cert to an Elastic load balancer, with the EC2 instance behind it.

If you prefer to use a 3rd party cert, then you will need a domain in Route 53, an alias the IP number to the domain.